# Can't access nested stateful objects in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access a nested object in ReactJS. This is what the object looks like:

```
const characteristics = [
        { id: "geo", content: 'Geopolitical' },
        { id: "dog", content: 'Dog Loving' },

    ];

    const starterColumns = {
        "1": {
            name: 'I am',
            items: characteristics
            },
        "2": {
            name: 'fullstack developer',
            items: []
        }
    }

    const [columns, setColumns] = useState(starterColumns);
```

This is the error I get when I try to `console.log(columns['2']['items']['0']['id'])`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Does this have to do with the fact that I am working with a stateful variable? Is something funky going on with the nested objects? Thanks for the help!

## EDIT

The problem was that there was no object in the column so I had no object to access. Now the problem outstanding is how do I fill that void without displaying a new drag and drop piece. Thanks for helping!

## EDIT

I used a `try/catch` statement to check the object so if it is empty, nothing happens.

Comment: Well you didn't put any items in your second column, so it's impossible to get the ID of the first one

Comment: Also, `items` is an array, access it using `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch only for errors that you can't handle

To access an element use dot notation whenever it's possible instead of using bracket notation []

When there is an empty array in the items you can't access to the id you will get an error so the solution is to check if the array is not empty

`columns['2'].items.length > 0`

To access the first element of an array you have to use [0] instead of ['0']

try this solution

```js
if (columns['2'].items.length > 0) {
  console.log(columns['2'].items[0].id)
}
```